# Batch: Copy only files newer than date and time

Tags: date, datetime, batch-file, copy

I need a script that **copies files that are newer** than a specified time (read from a file) from a directory and subfolders to a mirroring folder structure (that needs to be created). However, this needs to take account of **date and time**, not just date.

I can't seem to find a way to do this using batch / robocopy or another approach. Any suggestions would be appreciated, ideally not using powershell (I realise it can probably do it, but I've never used it and the learning curve seems a bit steep for now).

I can adjust the date/time saved in the file to fit any format.

So, say date-time is 2016-08-17-18-00-00, then

```
Org\A\1.txt     (2016-08-17-18-01-00) > Target\A\1.txt
Org\A\2.txt     (2016-08-17-17-00-00) > (not copied, as too old)
Org\B\C\D\3.txt (2016-08-18-09-00-00) > Target\B\C\D\3.txt
```

I probably need to use a `forfiles` loop, but not sure how to take account of time as well as date.

Comment: you have such a wonderful format - you are able to do just string comparison `if "2016-08-17-18-01-00" gtr "2016-08-17-18-00-00" ...`. Use a `for` loop to process the file. `for /?`, `if /?`

Comment: Use forfiles to generate an exclude.txt file containing all of the old filenames. Then pass that to `xcopy /EXCLUDE:exclude.txt`

Comment: @FloatingKiwi: `forfiles` works with dates only, no times.

Comment: Yes, but it can output @ftime which allows you to filter by that.

Comment: This looks useful! How do I get `forfiles` to output `fdate` in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format (or something in that order)? It seems to produce `DD\MM\YYYY`, at least in my locale.

Comment: These suggestions sounded promising, but I couldn't them to work. the `for` loop's file date + time is given in the format `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm`, which I cannot readily string-compare. And I can't see a way to transform it on the fly. `Forfiles` works by dates and I can't see a way to filter by time.. maybe you can explain what you mean? With `forfiles` I can't seem to copy files of a certain date either, only _of and newer_ or _of and older_... Any further / more detailed suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set compare=201608171800

for /r %%F in (*) do (
  set file=%%~fF
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=.=" %%I in ('wmic datafile where name^="!file:\=\\!" get lastmodified /format:list') do (
   if "%%I" geq "%compare%" for /f "tokens=2,* delims=\" %%A in ("%%~fF") do echo %%~fF -- N:\target\%%B
  )
)
```

you may have to adapt the "2" in `tokens=2,*` to your needs.

Note: this is slow, because of `wmic`
because of string comparison this works with `%compare%` format of `YYYYMMDDhhmmss` or `YYYYMMDDhhmm` or even `YYYY`.

Comment: Thanks. If anyone is looking at this and knows a pure batch way of doing this, I would really appreciate it. Though it might just not exist.

Comment: I meant without WMIC.

Comment: yeah - you *could*  use `dir /tw`, but this would be dependent of locale settings (date-format) and you have to put a lot of code to reformat to a comparable format (YYYY-MM-DD). Better to use `wmic` or even "non-batch-utilities" like powershell, java or vbs (all of it should be available on a standard windows installation and can be called from batch)

Comment: I was getting an error due to commas in the filename.
, - Invalid alias verb.
So I changed the code to :
for /f "tokens=2 delims=.=" %%I in ('wmic datafile where ^(name^="%file:\=\\%"^) get lastmodified /format:list') do (